# ReactJS: 2 api calls updating the same object - possible conflict?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React application where I want 2 separate REST API calls, called one after another, to update the same object. It's like this:

```
getAllTRLabs(
  (data) => {
    let newLabs = labsAllTypes
    newLabs.tr = data.translation_labs
    setLabsAllTypes(newLabs)
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
)

getAllEduLabs(
  (data) => {
    let newLabs = labsAllTypes
    newLabs.edu = data.eduLabs
    setLabsAllTypes(newLabs)
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
)
```

getAllTRLabs and getAllEduLabs handle the API calls and they are defined as function(onsuccess, onerror). So basically for each API call the labsAllTypes object is updated with the results (getAllTRLabs updates the "tr" field, and getAllEduLabs updates the "edu" field).
Now it seems to work, but I am a bit worried there might be a conflict between the 2 API calls, if they try to update labsAllTypes simultaneously and we end up with only one of the updates saved. So my question is, does React guard against such conflicts? Or are my fears valid, and if yes, how could I better implement this?

Comment: definitely need to see how `setLabsAllTypes` is done. and where `labsAllTypes` is assigned.

Comment: It's assigned via useState hook: const [labsAllTypes, setLabsAllTypes] = React.useState({})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by using Promise.all():

```
const paths_array = ['translation_labs_api', 'edu_labs_api']
const fetches_array = paths_array.map(path => fetch(path, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: 'GET',
    }))

Promise.all(fetches_array)
    .then(data_array =>
          Promise.all(
            data_array.map(data => {
              if (data.ok){
                return data.json();
              } else {
                throw(new Error(data.status+' - '+data.statusText));
              }
            })
          )
        )
   .then(data_array => {
      let newLabs = {}

      data_array.forEach(data => {
         if (data.translation_labs){
            newLabs.tr = data.translation_labs
         } else if (data.edu_labs){
            newLabs = data.edu_labs
         }
      })
    
      setLabsAllTypes(newLabs)
   })
   .catch(error => {
       function_to_execute_on_error(error)
   })

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try make use of spread operator.

```
getAllTRLabs(
  (data) => {
    let newLabs = labsAllTypes
    setLabsAllTypes({...newLabs, 'tr': data.translation_labs})
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
)

getAllEduLabs(
  (data) => {
    let newLabs = labsAllTypes
    setLabsAllTypes({...newLabs,'edu': data.eduLabs})
  },
  (err) => console.log(err)
)
```